# python reg exp: how to delete a field delimited by [ and ] from a string

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a file and every line looks like this:

```
2013-04-23 16:04:12.276 BLA[16878:950f] 'asdf' : 0, 'asds': 0, 'adf': 0
```

I need to replace the part `BLA[16878:950f]` with a `,` .

Note that the text `BLA` is always the same, but the text within `[`and `]` is always different and can have a different length.

What I need at the end is:

```
2013-04-23 16:04:12.276, 'asdf' : 0, 'asds': 0, 'adf': 0
```

Any ideas? I'm very bad at regular expressions, but I think this is the only way.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> line = "2013-04-23 16:04:12.276 BLA[16878:950f] 'asdf' : 0, 'asds': 0, 'adf': 0"
>>> re.sub(r'BLA\[[^\]]+\]', ',', line)
"2013-04-23 16:04:12.276 , 'asdf' : 0, 'asds': 0, 'adf': 0"
```

I think you actually want to replace `spaceBLA[16878:950f]` though: so just add that space in if you wish

Comment: Wow, thanks. this is exactly what I was needing. Why must reg exp always need to be so complicated? :-)

Comment: @otmezger `[`, `]` are metacharacters so there is some weird escaping to be done

Comment: that's exactly why I was not able to find out by myself. but this is how `XCode` prints the result of `NSLog` into the console.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm very bad at regular expressions, but I think this is the only way.

FWIW, it can be done without regular expressions...

```
>>> s = "2013-04-23 16:04:12.276 BLA[16878:950f] 'asdf' : 0, 'asds': 0, 'adf': 0"
>>> i1 = s.find('[')
>>> i2 = s.find(']')
>>> '%s,%s' % (s[:i1-4], s[i2+1:])
"2013-04-23 16:04:12.276, 'asdf' : 0, 'asds': 0, 'adf': 0"
```

...but this will only work if you can guarantee that there's only one occurrence of each of the `[` and `]` characters in the string.

However, jamylak's solution will be more reliable.

Comment: Thanks, I'll use this for easier tasks in the future.